# Making a formula that adds to a value based off of the data in other cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to make a formula that does the following (in the order below) in Column AJ:

```
If Column AA is blank, then add the dollar amount in Column Z to AJ
If Column V = "Us" AND Column AA = "Them", then add the dollar amount in Column Z to AJ 
If Column AG is blank, then add the dollar amount in Column AF to AJ
If Column V = "Us" AND Column AG = "Them", then add the dollar amount in Column AF to AJ
```

So each step would add the new dollar amount (if any) to the existing amount in Column AJ.

I know how to do each of these lines as separate formulas, but I'm struggling how to combine them so that the formula will check the right columns and then continue to add up the sum.

Any help or guidance would be amazing!!!

Comment: pls share your 4 formulas

Comment: also what means "in Column Z to AJ" ? can you clarfy?

Comment: To clarify  "in Column Z to AJ", I meant "Add the dollar amount that is in Column Z to the amount that is in Column AJ". Does that make sense? 

And I don't have formulas for each of these, but the first could be done by something like the following:
IF(AA2="",Z2+AJ2)

The 2nd and 4th rows I think could maybe be done with a query. But I have no idea how to do all four at once within one formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((AA:AA="")+((V:V="Us")*(AA:AA="Them")), Z:Z,
 IF((AG:AG="")+((V:V="Us")*(AG:AG="Them")), AF:AF,)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(V:V&Z:Z&AA:AA&AF:AF&AG:AG),
 IF((AA:AA="")+((V:V="Us")*(AA:AA="Them")), Z:Z)+
 IF((AG:AG="")+((V:V="Us")*(AG:AG="Them")), AF:AF, ), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go! I do have a question though, how would I incorporate this into a sheet that has headers in the first two rows? So it would only need to work rows 3 and down

Comment: like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((AA2:AA="")+((V2:V="Us")*(AA2:AA="Them")), Z2:Z,
 IF((AG2:AG="")+((V2:V="Us")*(AG2:AG="Them")), AF2:AF,)))`

Comment: It looks like this is super close, but not exactly working as needed. I think I explained it wrong (honestly I was a bit confused myself on the logic needed). 

Both parts of your formula are working, however they need to be added together. An example would be in the screenshot I've added, Row 7 would need to be equal to $1,850 (it meets criteria of "Us" in V7 and AG is blank, so add Z and AF together to get AJ7). Does that make sense??

https://i.gyazo.com/3f7f377b134dcb4acdc8f8ed7939de7e.png